# Vue provide/inject logic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I want to fetch the current user if user is authenticated (the auth state I get from 0auth) and provide it to children components:

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { provide, ref, watch } from "vue";

const fetchedUser = ref(null);
const error = ref(null);

const { isAuthenticated,user: authUser } = useSomething();

provide(
  "user",
  computed(() => fetchedUser.value)
);

watch(isAuthenticated, async (newAuthenticated) => {
  if (newAuthenticated) {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/users/${authUser.value.email}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const json = await response.json();
      // I load the user properly here, can access it
      console.log({ json });
      fetchedUser.value = json.user;
    } else {
      error.value = "Failed to get user";
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is the child:

```
...
const currentUser = inject("user");

const k = ref(null);

watch(currentUser, (newValue) => {
  console.log({newValue});
  k.value = newValue;
});

console.log(k.value);
...
```

It always returns the initial value. I tried many things but can't get it right.

Comment: { immediate: true } is missing for watchers. Otherwise it's ok and there's no explanation for "It always returns the initial value". I'm not sure if `computed(() => fetchedUser.value)` is justified. If user is an object it still can be mutated if k is mutated